# What's the meaning of "blew my degree"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

consider this statement:

> I have always been a loner, trying to be someone I am not and as I am too soft and empathetic, I get taken advantage of a lot.. spend my Uni years on the net talking to people far away from me to have a 'connection' and thus, **blew** my degree so it's really a useless piece of paper.

What's the meaning of *blew* in this statement?

I'm kinda confused. I thought he said he has made connections there on the online university, but he blew his "degree" -- it's his 'degree' that he blew? but at the same time he is saying, by my understanding, he has gotten his degree, but it's just a "useless piece of paper"? I'm very confused.

Answer (score 3):

It essentially means that the speaker did not make interpersonal connections at the university, and thus missed out on the opportunities there.

### informal

To completely lose or miss (an opportunity).
"the wider issues were to show that politicians had blown it"

synonyms:   spoil, ruin, bungle, mess up, fudge, muff; 
More expose (a stratagem).
"a man whose cover was blown"
synonyms:   expose, reveal, uncover, disclose, divulge, unveil, betray, leak
"his cover was blown"

[definition](https://www.google.com/search?q=blew&rlz=1C1CHWA_enUS599US601&oq=blew&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j69i61&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8): look at the fifth definition in the dropdown

Comment: I'm kinda confused. I thought he said he has made connections there on the online university, but he blew his "degree" -- it's his 'degree' that he blew? but at the same time he is saying, by my understanding, he has gotten his degree, but it's just a "**useless** piece of paper"? I'm very confused.

Comment: I believe that it's implying that they were at a physical university, but instead of networking, they spent time on the internet and talked with people there.  A significant component of getting jobs is who you know, which is one thing that going to a university is for. Therefore, even though the speaker may have gotten a degree, it's not very useful without the connections made to go with it. Does that make any more sense?

Comment: Even though he received a degree, he spent all his time chatting with people on-line instead of concentrating on studying. He does not explicitly say why it's a useless piece of paper, maybe his knowledge was not very deep  or his grades were not very good.

Comment: In this context, "blew my degree" is basically an abbreviated way of saying, "blew (or _squandered_) the many opportunities that should have come along with earning a degree (to the point where my degree doesn't help me now)."